# CefSharp3 Can't navigate back

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am currently using CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf (CEF branch 1750 and CefSharp 33.0.0) to evaluate my issue. I just added a button to the MainView.xaml like this `<Button Command="{Binding WebBrowser.BackCommand}">Back</Button>`. The buttons enable state is updated on loading a site (once the site is loaded it is pressable). But clicking on it doesn't work to navigate back.

My second approach was to execute a java script snippet on click `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("history.back()");` But this doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, but your answer gave me an idea, I hope my solution works for you.

The first page showed by the browser is like a blank page, so, when this blank page is loaded, I assign the URL, through `FrameLoadEnd` event of the browser.

I have a flag to avoid assign the URL more than one time.

```
Browser.FrameLoadEnd += delegate
                        {
                            if (!flag)
                            {
                                Browser.Address = "http://www.google.com.mx";
                                flag = true;
                            }
                        };
```

Looks like with this the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My investigation result is that if you set the URL too early - on creation of the browser object `ChromiumWebBrowser` until up to about 250ms (try&error value on my machine) - at least the back-function and JavaScript-injection won't work. The `Initialized` event is not a solution because it is too early. Apart from this the site will be rendered fine and you can browse the web. This was the part which distracted me and let me search elsewhere.